# avoiding two step verification to https://sellercentral.amazon.com

Tags: python-2.7, firefox, selenium-webdriver, verification

I have a Selenium-python script which automatically logs in to https://sellercentral.amazon.com and downloads the report.
Tools used:
**Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (Azure VM)

Xvfb(To run the firefox in headless mode)

Firefox 51.0.0

Selenium**

This script was running perfectly as I have to provide only username and password to log in to Amazon Seller Central website.

From 1st Nov 2017, Amazon Seller Central has introduced two step verification where we get a **code** text on registered device after log in which we have to enter in given text box.

Here, we have option to add the device as trusted device so from next login we don't have to verify using verification code.

I have added this machine as trusted device by manually login to Amazon Seller central so my script will not have to ask for verification code.

But, I can see when I run the script after login I get the verification code notification.

So, Amazon Seller Central is treating it as a new device and asking for verify the login. But when I try to login to Amazon Seller Central website manually it is not asking to verify the login.

I am not sure what is going wrong. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There is probably a cookie set in your browser. You would need to put that same cookie in the request for it "look like the same device".

Comment: Have you tried with creating a firefox profile and using the same profile for selenium tests.

Comment: @juunas, could you please refer any article where I'll get an exact idea about how to load cookies in the request.

Comment: @juunas, Yes that is what I did exactly. I have cookie saved in the firefox default profile. So, next time when I executed my selenium script I loaded the default profile in firefox profile and it worked.

Comment: @Grasshopper, No I am using the default profile of firefox. Is it necessary to create new profile?